# Session referrer in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
function procLogin($user,$pass,$remember){

      global $session, $form;
      $retval = $session->login($user, $pass ,$remember);
      if($retval){
        header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
         echo "comign in";
        return 'yes';


        }else{

         $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
         $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
         header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
        return 'no';    

        }

   }
```

How can i call this in flex, i mean if the session is user i want a different page and session is admin i want a different page.

But how do i get the session value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure what you want exactly, ill try.

The session value is stored in a cookie called PHPSESSID.

[Here's a small tutorial](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashCookie/index.html) on how to read and write cookies in Flash